# UI-bootstrap: Cannot read property 'remove' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using ui-bootstrap(accordion) for angular. 
Also im creating recursive templates with directives to display nested object structure smthng like this:

```
[
{
    name: String("Name1"),
    key: String("name1"),
    value: String("some text")
},
{
    name: String("Name2"),
    key: String("name2"),
    value: {[
        {
            name: String("Object1"),
            key: String("object1"),
            value: {[   
                {
                    name: String("Object1 Name3"),
                    key: String("object1.name3"),
                    value: Object()
                },
            ]}
        },
        {
            name: String("Name4"),
            key: String("name4"),
            value: String()
        },
    ]}
},
{
    name: String("Name5"),
    key: String("name5"),
    value: Number("44")
}
]
```

To make displaying of complex object structure possible I used directive with recursive template and its works fine.

Also I have two buttons: "Edit" - makes possible edit values and "Cancel" - turns all input fields to disable mode.

When I'm pressing "Cancel" button I got this exception:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null
at onDestroyTooltip (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angularjs/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.js?8b58789:2248:20)
at Scope.$broadcast (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angularjs/angular.js?8b58789:12691:28)
at Scope.$destroy (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angularjs/angular.js?8b58789:12349:14)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angularjs/angular.js?8b58789:1017:18)
at HTMLDivElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/jquery/jquery.js?8b58789:3332:58)
at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle.eventHandle (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/jquery/jquery.js?8b58789:2941:81)
at Object.jQuery.event.trigger (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/jquery/jquery.js?8b58789:3210:40)
at jQuery.fn.extend.triggerHandler (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/jquery/jquery.js?8b58789:3874:45)
at removePatch [as remove] (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angularjs/angular.js?8b58789:2213:21)
at Object.leave (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angularjs/angular.js?8b58789:4143:17)
```

Line:  `onDestroyTooltip (http://localhost:8080/js/lib/angularjs/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.js?8b58789:2248:20)` in stacktrace points to this part of ui-bootsrap code:

```
scope.$on('$destroy', function onDestroyTooltip() {
        $timeout.cancel( transitionTimeout );
        $timeout.cancel( popupTimeout );
        unregisterTriggers();
        tooltip.remove(); // <-- ERROR here!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
        tooltip.unbind();
        tooltip = null;
      });
```

Can some one explain me what went wrong? Why im getting this exception and how I can prevent it?